# How to use a entrybox to set a var

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to make a user interface where the user gives his name in a entry-box, when i try to print the name variable something goes wrong en PY_VAR gets printed.

```
import tkinter as tk


class TestApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.geometry('400x500')
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid()

    def save(self,var1name):
        print(var1name)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        var1name = tk.StringVar()
        #Entry of basic information
        tk.Label(self, text="Please enter setup").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
        tk.LabelFrame(self, text="labelframe").grid()
        tk.Label(self, text="Name: ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
        tk.Entry(self,textvar=var1name).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="W")

        tk.Button(self, text="Set",
                  command=lambda: master.save(var1name)).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="E")

        #tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                  #command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).grid(row=9, column=2, sticky="E")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

i expected a name printed on the Python interface but it printed PY_VAR instead

Comment: `print(var1name.get())`

Comment: Did you try searching for `PY_VAR0` on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var1name is a reference to a Tkinter.StringVar object. You need to call its **get method** to access the value that it represents, for example:

```
print (var1name.get())
```

> The **get** method returns the current value of the variable, as a Python
>   object.

In your code:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        var1name = tk.StringVar()
        # Entry of basic information
        tk.Label(self, text="Please enter setup").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
        tk.LabelFrame(self, text="labelframe").grid()
        tk.Label(self, text="Name: ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
        tk.Entry(self, textvar=var1name).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="W")

        tk.Button(self, text="Set",
                  command=lambda: master.save(var1name.get())).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="E")
```

Comment: You have conflicting statements in your answer. 1st you say to do `print (var1name.get())` then you say to do `master.save(var1name.get())`. If you do one or the other it works but if you do both it will not work.

Comment: print (var1name.get()) is just example !

Comment: Yes but you don't say that. You tell the OP to do both. I am just saying you need to be more clear or else this will cause an error. IE: Instead of saying "In your code" you could say "You can also use `get()` in the command". The reason I say to be more clear is due to language barriers and context. The way it was originally worded sounded more like. Do `print(var1name.get())` and do `master.save(var1name.get())`.

Comment: hmm, interesting, i had note 'In your code: ...' , but I will consider your comment